# Nodejs Redis HSET & HGET insert to dataset Error

Tags: node.js, redis, hashset

I am trying to insert comments for post in redis with HSET as preferred option, but getting error .
Below is the code :

```
 var commmentData ={
          id : id,
          comment : req.body.comment,
          postId : req.body.postId,
          userId : req.body.userId
        }
   redisClient.hset('comment', commmentData, function(err, reply) {
                      if (err) throw err;
                      console.log("Reply : "+ reply);
                      res.json(errorResponse.res.SaveSuccess);      
                  });
```

I am still clueless between HMSET or HSET, which one should be used.

Comment: Looks like you need HMSET - the 'M' is for multiple, as in setting multiple fields on the Hash. It's like doing HMSET multiple times for different fields.

Comment: does insert solution resame, i have to store everything in stringify format ? like below code  : 
redisClient.hmset('comment', JSON.stringify(commmentData), function(err, reply) {
     if (err) throw err;

     console.log("Reply : "+ reply);     
 });

Answer (score 0):

Redis stores everything as a string (the protocol is text-based, after all).

If you want to store objects in Redis, make sure that you serialize them (`JSON.stringify()`) before saving and de-serialize (`JSON.parse()`) after retrieving.

Try:

```
 var commmentData ={
      id : id,
      comment : req.body.comment,
      postId : req.body.postId,
      userId : req.body.userId
 }

 redisClient.hset('comment', id, JSON.stringify(commmentData), function(err, reply) {
     if (err) throw err;

     console.log("Reply : "+ reply);     
 });
```

Comment: If we are storing everything in string then how search would be done. 
Does HGET or HMGET uses any search index parameter. 
For example if we want to search with userId or date.

Comment: I have tried above solution but still getting errors : 

c:\Users\ACER\Documents\GitHub\api\routes\comments.js:74
                    if (err) throw err;
                                   ^
Error: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'hset' command

Comment: @Suvittruf Can you please share an example. I am still getting errors.